# Difference between Symbol and Symbols

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

These two are suspected duplicate tags, [symbol](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbol) and [symbols](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols).

Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Tags have been merged and synonymed.